# Sqlx WHERE IN query with long list

Tags: postgresql, go, amazon-redshift, postgresql-performance

I'm using sqlx to perform a query in my Go code. The query has a long list of values (~10,000) that I need to filter on in the WHERE IN (?) clause. This causes a huge slowdown in performance. How can I optimize such a query? Also, this query is being performed on a Redshift cluster, so indexing a column isn't a solution to improve the query performance.

```
values := []int64{143, 123, 123, 542....} // ~10,000 elements
query, args, err := sqlx.In(query, values)
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}

query = dbInterface.Rebind(query)   
err = dbInterface.Select(&list, query, args...)
```

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE some_id IN (?) ORDER BY created_at;
```

Comment: Please show the query and the type of values to insert. Where do those values come from? From your go code? A file? Another table?

Comment: @Patrick just updated it

Comment: You could try taking the min/max of your values, querying that range and then filtering only for the records you want in Go code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ultimately created a TEMP TABLE for the ids and performed a JOIN. This greatly improved the query performance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make `sqlx` produce one of these:

- the `values` syntax:

  ```
  where some_id in (values (143), (123))
  ```
- join an array:

  ```
  select *
  from
      t
      inner join
      unnest(array[143, 123]) u (id) on u.id = t.id
  ```

Comment: Unfortunately Redshift doesn't have support for values nor unnest.